# What is diff command telling me?

Tags: diff, git-diff

I am so confused because I don't see a difference in these files. I run the following:

```
diff -B -w -b foo/user_advances.go bar/user_advances.go
```

and I get this:

```
36a37
>   Executed        bool            `boil:"executed" json:"executed" toml:"executed" yaml:"executed"`
40d40
<   Executed        bool            `boil:"executed" json:"executed" toml:"executed" yaml:"executed"`
59a60
>   Executed        string
63d63
<   Executed        string
77a78
>   Executed:        "executed",
81d81
<   Executed:        "executed",
143a144
>   Executed        whereHelperbool
147d147
<   Executed        whereHelperbool
161a162
```

but I don't see any differences here, so what is going on?

Comment: Look at spaces, tabs and end lines. For example on windows lines end with \r\n and on linux it is just \n.

Comment: the -B -w and -b flags are supposed to ignore whitespace tho

Comment: I do not think that your files are identical. Just look at the first line: 36a37 which means that "After line 36 in the first file, a line needs to be added: line 37 from the second file." It then shows us what that line is.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is the lines in the file are in a slightly different order.

The `36a37` means that the following text must be added to the first file after line 36, to obtain what is in the second file. The `40d40` means that the following text must be deleted from line 40 of the first file to obtain what is in the second file. Since the text in both cases is the same, this means that the contents of line 40 were deleted and moved to line 37.

Similarly, the contents of line 63 were deleted and moved to line 60. And the contents of line 81 were deleted and moved to line 78. And so on...

Adding `-c` to the command-line might make this clearer. The `-c` tells diff to provide a 3-line context around each difference, so you would more easily see the difference between the files.